# Travel to India from UAE, passsport expires in Jan 2017

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india

I have UAE residence visa valid till November 2018. My passport expires on 10-01-2017. I want to travel to India in June 2016 and come back in August 2016. Is it possible without renewing my passport?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

A residency visa (like yours) is not subject to the normal requirements that a temporary visit visa (such as the one on-arrival or transit) are subject to.

Have a safe trip.